# Test multiple android applications with same integration tests?

Tags: java, android, maven, integration-testing

I think this is a long shot, but...

We have such project structure:

```
common-library
    - denmark
          - application
    - france
          - application
    - application-xxxxxx
          - application
          - integration-tests
```

Each application has different configuration, translations, different package names and so on, but in all they are almost the same. They have the same features, same user interface etc.

Only one of our applications is now tested with integration tests with `Robotium`. Is there a way to "share" same integration tests for other applications?

It would be perfect to have "common tests" and custom/specific tests for each application. Is it at all possible?

We're using maven and Jenkins for our needs.

Any other approaches or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is migrating to Gradle an option? With the Gradle build system you can define the different versions as flavours and the integration tests will live next to them (the manifest would be automatically updated when you call the correct target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, assuming you need to maintain one set of integration tests only, I would go in direction of having:

- separate maven module holding integration tests only
- and in it I'd introduce multiple maven profiles, where each one would have specified maven dependency on one of the modules to be tested only
- build can later switch between the profiles to activate the particular build only

As some notes on integration testing options say (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) and I believe it would affect this approach as well:

> The disadvantage of doing it this way is that it tends to separate the integration tests from the code they're attempting to test. As a result, you may find that no one "owns" the integration tests; typically you'll have some one person whose job it is to analyze the integration tests and find bugs. QA is hard, but it's even harder when it's unclear who "owns" test failures.

Another problem could be if you run your builds including integration tests (via Jenkins) on code change automatically. Module dependencies would not launch your integration tests automatically. Rather you might need to define one Jenkins job per profile and define the correct jobs sequence manually. 
E.g.: If Jenkins built denmark app => build integration, with profile denmark, ...

Comment: This actually might work. But I still might have some problems due to required `AndroidManifest.xml` files. Their configuration is different for reach application.

Comment: well, not sure about the particular files, but if these could be bundled with app, I would do so, otherwise, I'd make sure I have the right one included depending on maven profile in the integration test module.